# Magento 2: How to delete order's invoice, credit memo & shipment programmatically?

Tags: magento2, orders, shipment, creditmemo, magento2.1.5

I would like to delete order's invoice, credit memo & shipment programmatically.

How to achieve this by passing only order id?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are few steps are required for this.

### Load order by Order Factory

Inject the factory class **`\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory`** on **`__construct`** class.for getting order.

*Then order get by order id*

```
 $order = $this->orderFactory->create()->load($orderId);
```

### Get Invoice collection from Order object

Get *Invoice collection* from Order object  using ***getInvoiceCollection()***

As ***you want  run delete operation*** then you  should set  **`$this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);`**

### Get Shipment collection from Order object

Get ***Shipment collection*** from Order object  using `getShipmentsCollection()`

### Get credit memo collection from Order object

Get credit memo collection from Order object  using **`getCreditmemosCollection()`**

### code:

> ```
> <?php
> namespace [YournameSapce];
> class DeleteorderInvoiceetc
> {
>   protected $order;
>   protected $redirectFactory;
>   protected $registry;
>
>   public function __construct(
>       ........
>       \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
>       \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
>   ) {
>       ......
>       $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
>       $this->registry = $registry;
>   }   
>   public function Order(){
>       $orderId = 'xyz';
>       if(!$this->order){  
>           $this->order = $this->orderFactory->create()->load($orderId);
>       }
>        return $this->order;
>   }
>   public function deleteInvoices(){
>
>       if(!$this->Order()){
>           return;
>       }
>
>       if($this->registry->registry('isSecureArea')){
>           $this->registry->unregister('isSecureArea');
>       }
>       $this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
>
>       $_invoices = $this->Order()->getInvoiceCollection();
>
>       if($_invoices){
>           foreach($_invoices as $invoice){
>               $invoice->delete();
>           }
>       }
>
>   }
>   /*
>   * Shipemrnt delete
>   */
>   public function deleteShipments(){
>
>       if(!$this->Order()){
>           return;
>       }
>
>       if($this->registry->registry('isSecureArea')){
>           $this->registry->unregister('isSecureArea');
>       }
>       $this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
>
>       $_shipments = $this->Order()->getShipmentsCollection();
>
>       if($_shipments){
>           foreach($_shipments as $_shipment){
>               $_shipment->delete();
>           }
>       }
>
>   }
>       /*
>   * Credit memo delete
>   */
>   public function deleteCreditmemos(){
>
>       if(!$this->Order()){
>           return;
>       }
>
>       if($this->registry->registry('isSecureArea')){
>           $this->registry->unregister('isSecureArea');
>       }
>       $this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
>
>       $_creditmemos = $this->Order()->getCreditmemosCollection();
>
>       if($_creditmemos){
>           foreach($_creditmemos as $_creditmemo){
>               $_creditmemo->delete();
>           }
>       }
>
>   }   
> }
> ```

Comment: HI @Amit It's required to do isSecureArea to true?

Comment: yes.  you want run delete operation magento exclude admin

Comment: Hi Amit It will delete that thing. But in Order if I had refunded some amount then it's still showing

Comment: Thanks @AmitBera you saved the day :)